Add one more image by keeping previous images as it is
I am working on mvc. I have made an editing page where descriptions of a specific title are shown along with the multiple images added with a particular description. I want to make a button that adds one more image without removing the previously uploaded images. The new image should be added along with previously uploaded images.
I tried this from the controller side.
public ActionResult EditDescriptions(List<AddStoryDTO> model, HttpPostedFileBase[] Images)
        {
            if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
                {
                    var description = model[i];
                    var uploadedImages = Request.Files.GetMultiple($"Images_{i}");
                    List<string> imageNames = new List<string>();

                    
                    if (uploadedImages != null && uploadedImages.Count > 0 && uploadedImages[0].ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var image in uploadedImages)
                        {
                            if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                var imageName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Admin/Content/StoryImage/"), imageName);
                                image.SaveAs(path);
                                imageNames.Add(imageName);

                            }
                        }

                       
                        description.Imagename = string.Join(",", imageNames);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                        description.Imagename = model[i].Imagename;
                    }

                   
                    bll.UpdateDescriptionAndImage(description);
                }

               
                return RedirectToAction("TitleList");
            }

            return View(model);
        }



Ok. So...where are you stuck with that? Have you tried anything? Researched anything? I somehow doubt you're the first person with this kind of requirement. Presumably your server-side code needs to be involved in this, so it saves a new image and doesn't delete/overwrite previous ones. But you've only shown us the view where you display them and have the new input. It's unclear what the problem is or what you need. See [ask] please. Bear in mind that Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. You can ask us about a specific problem within your attempt to implement your desired feature.


You need to show how you plan to post the image from the View as it doesn't contain any form tag.
You need to show the BE code in order to provide additional help


Your question is not clear.

I am sorry for the issues, I am new to coding and stack overflow, I have edited the question and mentioned the logic that I have tried in the edit controller.
